# Помогите вывести на друк отрицательные елементы массива

Tags: c, массивы

Задан массив {1.2, 0.18, 1.32, -3.5, 12.6, 14.3, 1.23, 2.41, 7.3, -26.36, 8.2, 2.18, -1.2, 4.6, 0.153}
Нужно вывести на друк отрицательные елементы с их номерами(можете помочь и без, главное вывести)

Comment: а какие именно проблемы у вас с выводом? кстати, что значит "вывести на друк"?

Comment: просто вывести, друк это просто так написал, потому что printf)

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int  A [] ={1.2, 0.18, 1.32, -3.5, 12.6, 14.3, 1.23, 2.41, 7.3, -26.36, 8.2, 2.18, -1.2, 4.6, 0.153}; Это я написал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надеюсь я правильно понял вашу задачу?

> Дан массив чисел, вывести на экран отрицательные и их номера в массиве.

Создали массив:

```
float mas[] = {1.2, 0.18, 1.32, -3.5, 12.6, 14.3, 1.23, 2.41, 7.3, -26.36, 8.2, 2.18, -1.2, 4.6, 0.153};
```

`float` т.к. числа дробные

Посчитали длину массива:

```
int masSize = sizeof(mas) / sizeof(float);
```

Т.е. количество байт, которые занимает сам массив мы делим на число байт, которые занимает 1 элемент массива, так получаем длину массива

Ну а дальше просто пробежались по всему массиву и вывели отрицательные:

```
for (int i = 0; i < masSize; i++) {
    if (mas[i] < 0) {
        printf("%d: %g\n", i, mas[i]);
    }
}
```

Код в итоге:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float mas[] = {1.2, 0.18, 1.32, -3.5, 12.6, 14.3, 1.23, 2.41, 7.3, -26.36, 8.2, 2.18, -1.2, 4.6, 0.153};
    int masSize = sizeof(mas) / sizeof(float);
    for (int i = 0; i < masSize; i++) {
        if (mas[i] < 0) {
            printf("%d: %g\n", i, mas[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Что он вывел после выполнения:

```
3: -3.5
9: -26.36
12: -1.2
```

Comment: лучший, спасибо))) сам бы не смог

Comment: @СтовбанОлександр если я вам помог, пометьте пожалуйста мое решение как ответ на ваш вопрос

Comment: пометил, спасибо

Comment: а что такое %g?

Comment: Выводит на экран максимально мало нулей после точки. Ну или как-то так. Если бы я написал %f он бы вывел несколько нулей, что обычно никому сильно не нужно. Можете сравнить разницу самостоятельно

Comment: и последнее, если б у меня был массив {1.2, 0.18, 1.32, -3.5, 12.6, 14.3, 1.23, 2.41, 7.3, -26.36, 8.2, 2.18, -1.2, 4.6, 0.153, -15.6, 10.8, -5.2, 1,76} и мне нужно вывести только 3 первые отрицательные елементы с их номерами в массиве, как это записать?

Comment: Посчитайте выведенные числа внутри if и остановите цикл break